# Relative location of RP1 and LOX tanks in Saturn V

Tags: liquid-fuel, saturn-v, lox

In Saturn V, the 2nd and 3rd stages had their fuel tank located above the LOX tank, but in the first stage, the LOX tank was located above the fuel tank. Is it because the individual stages had their own arrangement which was maintained as it is, or is there any specific reason for the difference in arrangement?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd stages used liquid hydrogen for fuel, not RP1.